# Find Nearest Latitude and Longitude

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

my question is , i have hotel info alone with their latitude and longitude in my database.now i want to find the nearest hotel from the given latitude and longitude .
for example :suppose latitude is 196.98575 and longitude is = 24.985644,
now based on this lat long i want to find the nearest hotel in 15 km, which i have available in my database .
please suggest me any idea or if you have any stored procedure please tell me so that i can avoid manually task.
i am using sql server.

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx

Comment: What version of Sql Server, is it 2008 or newer?

Comment: If your sql instance is 2008+ you have the 'geography' data type, that stores coordinates and has a built in haversine distance function. A while since I used it but shouldn't take much to google an example.

Comment: i am using Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

As was alluded to in a comment above, SQL Server has had native geospatial capabilities since SQL 2008. Here's my stab at a solution:

```
create table dbo.Hotels (
    HotelID int identity not null,
        constraint [PK_Hotels] primary key clustered (HotelID),
    Longitude decimal(15, 12) not null,
    Latitude decimal(14, 12) not null,
    geo as geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326)
)

insert into dbo.Hotels 
    (Longitude, Latitude)
values
    (-122.4167, 37.7833);
go

create procedure dbo.findHotels (@point geography, @distanceKM int = 15)
as
begin
    --SRID 4326 measures disances in meters, so use that measure
    declare @distanceM int = @distanceKM * 1000;

    select HotelID, @point.STDistance(geo) as [DistanceInM]
    from dbo.Hotels
    where @point.STDistance(geo) <= @distanceM
    order by @point.STDistance(geo);
end
go

declare @longitude decimal(15, 12) = -122.4168,
    @latitude decimal(14, 12) = 37.7832;
declare @p geography = geography::Point(@latitude, @longitude, 4326);

exec dbo.findHotels @p, 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates).there It  find places within a distance d=1000 km from M=(lat, lon)=(1.3963, -0.6981) in a database
*Lat and Lon that hold the coordinates in radians

here is the simple query according to this source

```
SELECT * FROM Places WHERE
    (Lat => 1.2393 AND Lat <= 1.5532) AND (Lon >= -1.8184 AND Lon <= 0.4221)
AND
    acos(sin(1.3963) * sin(Lat) + cos(1.3963) * cos(Lat) * cos(Lon - (-0.6981))) <= 0.1570;
```

Comment: what is Lat and Lon ,its parameter which we are passing or something else

Comment: table named Places with columns Lat and Lon that hold the coordinates in radians,

Comment: but it seems the answer of @Ben Thul prety forward

Comment: see in this code i need to pass two set of lat and long. but i have only one lat and long, and with this lat ,long i need to find nearest lat,long which is available in my database.